# Better to use 3rd Party Row-Level Permission App or to Filter Query Results in a Django View?

Tags: django, permissions, django-permissions, django-guardian

I am writing a Django app that involves the creation of documents. I have a few requirements:

1. Check to see if the user is able to view *any* documents at all.
2. If the user is allowed to view documents, only allow them to view documents they have permission for.

I have come up with two solutions and am wondering if one is philosophically/practically better than the other.

The two solutions I've come up with are:

**Solution One** (using third-party Django-Guardian)

`Models.py`

```
class Document(models.Model)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    document_content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ('view_document', 'View Document'),
    )
```

`views.py`

```
@permission_required('document.view_document', (Document, 'pk', 'document_id'))
def view_document(request, document_id):
    document = Document.objects.get(pk=document_id)
    return render_to_response("native/view_events.html",
    {
        'document' : document,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The downside I see to solution number one is that I have to explicitly set permissions every time I create an object, plus I have to hit the database twice: once to check permissions and again to retrieve the document object.

**Solution Two (using built-in Django permissions)**

`Models.py`

```
class Document(models.Model)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    document_content = models.TextField()
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ('view_document', 'View Document'),
    )
```

`views.py`

```
@permission_required('document.view_document')
def view_document(request, document_id):
    document = Document.objects.filter(pk=document_id, viewers__pk=request.user.pk)[0]
    return render_to_response("native/view_events.html",
    {
        'document' : document,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The downside I see to solution number one is that I have to do two checks, one to see if they are able to view documents at all, and one to see if they can view the particular document. A plus side to this is that if I have an admin that I want to be able to view all documents, I don't need to explicitly grant permission to each one; I can just give him the 'view document' permission.

It seems both solutions have their pros and cons. Is there one that is better in theory/practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the second approach better. Since, you can check the model level permission on the object. Though in the first I guess, you should be able to accomplish similar things. I am not sure but if django-guardian provides a way to check the permission inside the view code instead of the decorator. You could manually check for Model Level Permission. 
For example,

```
def view_doc(request, doc_id):
      if user can not view doc: #Model Level Permission
              return HttpResponse("Sorry can not view")
      if check django-guardian permission #Object Level Permission
               return HttpResponse("Can not view doc")
      #further code
```

But I would suggest the second approach since, you can create an api just to check permission and customize it which is more scalable.